# Vent portable a/c without a window

Tags: hvac

My son is moving into campus housing and needs a portable a/c for health reasons.  Is there a way to vent this unit without access to a window?  I read that you can vent into a large pot of water, is

Comment: You should be talking the the campus housing folks if your son has special needs while attending the school. If needed work out getting a room with a suitable window,

Answer (score 2):

All portable a/c units must be vented to outside. Usually this is through a window, but some apartment buildings have ports through walls for venting portable a/c units.

The idea that one could vent it into a bucket of water is not factual. It is either an innocently spread myth or an outright hoax.